# excel count unique values by group (cluster) in just a worksheet or a pivot table

Tags: excel, unique, distinct

count the number of unique items by cluster

```
---------------------
name | cluster
---------------------
john    1
john    1
john    1
james   1 
james   1
james   1
ron     2
ron     2
ron     2
```

and I would like to get....

```
--------------
cluster | count
--------------
1          2 (john and james)
2          1
```

I had an idea -- Maybe this can be done using a pivot table, but it seems only 2013 has the ability to count distinct? Can this be done with a pivot table calculated field?

**I have to be able to do it it normal excel with a formula, because other people I work with do not have access to excel powerpivot.** And whatever I do has to be able to be read by them.

Comment: So far I munged the data with powerpivot - but if possible I would like to do it without powerpivot

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an array formula**, e.g. with your original table in A1:B10 (with headers in row 1), and e.g. 1 in C2, in D2:

=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($B$2:$B$10=C2,MATCH($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$10)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$10))+1),1))

Regards

**Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).